# How do I find a repeater that is inside a user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I need to be able to export to excel a repeater. That part is no problem. I have the code for that in place. The issue is that the repeater I need to export is inside a usercontrol. I have one page that loads multiple reports and each of those reports is a different usercontrol.

The usercontrols themselves are nested in a div tag:

```
<div id="report_div" runat="server" style="width:100%;">
    <uc:report1 id="UCReport1" runat="server" />
    <uc:report2 id="UCReport2" runat="server" />
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to find is the repeater in the user control so I can render it for export to excel.

Comment: Do you have access to the code behind the user control? Have you looked at using the Controls property?

Comment: @the_lotus I have the user controls as well. The parent page loads the reports. I don't know that I've used the Controls property to be honest

Comment: If you have access to the user control, then you can add a property that would give access to the repeater to others. You could end up with UCReport1.TheRepeater

Answer (score 0):

You can use FindControl on the UserControl to locate the Repeater.

```
Repeater repeater = UCReport1.FindControl("Repeater1") as Repeater;
```

Now you have access to all the Repeater properties by using `repeater`.

```
int items = repeater.Items.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on when you want to get the data. You could do it on the DataBind() of the repeater and grab the data you need right when it is populated. Or if you need it later i suppose You could create an action event in the control itself and pass back the repeater..

```
    //in your User control class that holds the repeater..
    public static event Action<Repeater> GetRepeater;
    private Repeater repeater1;

    //populate and display repeater omited...

    private void onGetRepeater(Repeater  repeater)
    {
            GetRepeater?.invoke(repeater);
    }
    //just fire from somewhere. you 
    //could use the dataBind() page_Load, button click or whatever.
    //depending on when you need it. 
    protected void someBtnInYourControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs eArgs)
    {
          onGetRepeater(this.repeater1);
    }
```

now you can subscribe anywhere in your else in your project.

```
      public class OtherController : Controller
      {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //subscribe to the event

        UCReport1.GetRepeater += UCReport1_GetRepeater;
        return View();
    }

    private void UCReport1_GetRepeater(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater foo)
    {
        //when your event is trigger on the UC it will pass the repeater back so you 
          can use however.

         exportRepeaterToReport(foo);
    }
     }
```